# How to perform a task in another function and update the UI from there as the task progresses?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous

This is the code from my main viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var progressUI: UIProgressView!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        simulateDownload()
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func simulateDownload() -> Array<Tweak>
    {
        var results = [Tweak]()
        let searchQuery = "activator"
        let url = URL(string: "https://cydia.saurik.com/api/macciti?query=" + searchQuery)
        let urlData = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        var i = 0
        let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlData!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
        let resultTweaks = jsonResult?["results"] as! Array<Any>
        for tweak in resultTweaks
        {
            i += 1
            let progress = (Float(i) / Float(resultTweaks.count))
            results.append(Tweak(tweakdata: tweak as! [String: String]))
            DispatchQueue.main.async()
            {
                self.progressUI.progress = progress

            }
            print(progress)

        }
        print("done")
        return results
    }


}
```

This is my Tweak class, where the icons are downloaded when you create an instance of it

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Tweak
{
    var name, id, section, description, version, thumbURL: String
    var icon: UIImage
    init(tweakdata: Dictionary<String, Any>)
    {
        self.name = tweakdata["display"] as! String
        self.id = tweakdata["name"] as! String
        self.section = tweakdata["section"] as! String
        self.description = tweakdata["summary"] as! String
        self.version = tweakdata["version"] as! String
        self.thumbURL = "https://cydia.saurik.com/icon@2x/" + self.id + ".png"
        //load icon
        let imgURL = URL(string: self.thumbURL)
        let imgData = try? Data(contentsOf: imgURL!)
        self.icon = UIImage(data: imgData!)!

    }
}
```

I want to update the UIProgressView(progressUI) as each Tweak instance is made. But the UI only updates after the function returns. Can someone explain me all this works and how threading should be done?
I'm new to swift and async programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is already on the main thread, so It will block any UI updates, which not only disables progress bar updates, but also user interaction.

Any long running task should be run on background thread. Luckily, this is easy in Swift.

Since you are already updating progress view, something like this would work:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    simulateDownload()
}
```

instead of only calling `simulateDownload` in `viewDidLoad`

Please note that using this approach, you can't use the return value from the function directly from the main thread.

What you should do instead is providing the value from a closure, something like this:

```
func simulateDownload(@escaping closure: (_ result:Array<Tweak>) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        [...]
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            closure(results)
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
simulateDownload(closure: {
    results in
    [...]
})
```

This is only scratching the surface, If you want to learn more about closures in Swift, I suggest you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. 
How do I determine if a block is in main thread or not?
And `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{}` makes whatever given in the block run in a different thread?

Comment: To check if you're in the main thread, just check `Thread.isMainThread` , and yes, the block runs in a different thread.